# Cannot use border-radius CSS3 property with Flying Saucer

Tags: java, css, itext, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am working on a project where I need to convert an HTML to a PDF. I am using `Flying Saucer 9.1.6` from Maven Central for this. The subjacent PDF generation library is `IText 2.1.7`.

Although Flying Saucer Git repo states that it supports CSS3 border-radius syntax I am unable to achieve rounded corners with border-radius.

Here is the sample code

```
ITextRenderer pdfRenderer = new ITextRenderer();
String resumeHTML = "<html>\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "  <title>JS Bin</title>\n" +
            "    <style>\n" +
            "  .circle{\n" +
            "    border-radius: 50%;\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "</style>\n" +
            "</head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "  <img src='https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_original,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/3864710/original/isurunix.png'\n" +
            "       class='circle'\n" +
            "       >\n" +
            "  </img>\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
    pdfRenderer.setDocumentFromString(resumeHTML);
    pdfRenderer.layout();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sample.pdf");
    pdfRenderer.createPDF(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Valid HTML snippet used in the above sample

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
  .circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src='https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_original,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/3864710/original/isurunix.png'
       class='circle'
       >
  </img>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve rounded corners when using Flying Saucer?

Comment: @MrLister Can you elaborate on what is wrong? Do you mean the missing doctype declaration and closing image tag?
Flying Saucer looks for proper XHTML tag closing. That's the reason for the weird HTML. But it's valid for flying saucer.

Comment: Oh. In that case, sorry, apparently I don't know enough about Flying Saucer to be able to comment!

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for trying to help me in the ways you could.

Comment: No, the flying saucer version is **not** outdated and still supported as any other open source software is (as good or bad the support is for open source software). And whether the iText Corp. endorses FlyingSaucer or not, is irrelevant. Maybe some other company doesn't endorse the use of iText? Who cares? StackOverflow is a platform to efficiently help people and that is what we should focus on here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border-radius` works fine with divs, so you can use a div, and add your image with `background-image`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;height: 250px;
    background-image:url("https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_original,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/3864710/original/isurunix.png")
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is not the html, but the pdf generation that is not doing the conversion right