# border-radius css not working with flying saucer

Tags: java, html, css, flying-saucer

I want to use border-radius for my document, I was struggling and I found this code on stack overflow from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855068/cannot-use-border-radius-css3-property-with-flying-saucer) but results in this:
[output.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBLug.png), why?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;height: 250px;
    background-image:url("https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_original,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/3864710/original/isurunix.png")
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please in future add images instead of reference on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, flying saucer was out of date, sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use different structure.
Try this:

```
.circle {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;height: 250px;
    background-image:url("https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_original,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/3864710/original/isurunix.png")
  }
```

Comment: Still does not work when once  converted to pdf, maybe I am using a incorrect version of flying saucer?